# Python Selenium Like for Desktop Application Automation

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation

I have used Selenium for Website automation and testing.  I am looking for a Python based Selenium like module that will let me control a standard desktop application like Paint.exe on windows to control it.  I need a way to control clicks and selections automatically via Python.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy list bunch. Which one is best?

Comment: Desktop applications can be written with many GUI frameworks. Which of these do your app use? MFC? WinForms? WPF? QT? This is critically important for choosing an appropriate tool.

Comment: Selenium-like automation framework for desktop apps is https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop (it supports WinForms and WPF). pywinauto is good for native apps: http://pywinauto.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyAutoIt:
Here is example of:

```
open notepad
type some string into notepad, eg: “hello world”
close notepad without saving
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3

```
import autoit

autoit.run("notepad.exe")
autoit.win_wait_active("[CLASS:Notepad]", 3)
autoit.control_send("[CLASS:Notepad]", "Edit1", "hello world{!}")
autoit.win_close("[CLASS:Notepad]")
autoit.control_click("[Class:#32770]", "Button2")
```